# sparksql: disable INFO StatsReportListener

Tags: apache-spark

I have the spark 1.1 using YARN.
Every query I run it writes out the status giving INFO StatsReportListener, etc.
How do I disable this?  I am looking for the configuration where I can disable this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the logging level to WARN for example. From the official docs:

> Spark uses log4j for logging. You can configure it by adding a log4j.properties file in the conf directory. One way to start is to copy the existing log4j.properties.template locatedthere.

Comment: log4j.appender.logfile.File=/tmp/spark.log

Comment: Append this line to log4.properties file in the spark conf folder:log4j.appender.logfile.File=/tmp/spark.log, append the logs to a temp file like this.